# Get device handle of a Bluetooth Low Energy device

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Bluetooth Low Energy device to which I need send some values from the PC.I need to connect this device to the Windows 8 PC and should be communicate with it from my application (Visual C++, win 32 application). I already know the hardware ID and friendly name of the device.

Is there any API to establish connection to the device using this ID/ friendly name, and give a device handle so that I can use GATT APIs to send values to the device. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450825(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Bluetooth-Generic-4f4ea968

Bluetooth low energy is considered Network.Proximity just as NFC.

Comment: hi henrik thanks for replying!! can you expand a bit more on          " Bluetooth low energy is considered Network.Proximity just as NFC " please..